# Delta epsilon argument in general

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

When I want to prove something in mathematics fe an expression goes to zero, I can either use basic rules of 'limits' or I can use the epsilon-delta method. I have a feeling that it's more consistent and mathematical to use the epsilon-delta method.

So my question is:
"Is it more consistent to use the epsilon-delta method instead of basic limits calculations and why?"

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focus on $\epsilon$-$\delta$ is because you have to learn how it works.

The rules/theorems that you uses later on are proved directly or indirectly using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ aproach (because that's the definition).

The whole idea with formulating and proving theorems is that you should be able to use them in turn. It's no less consistent to use the theorem than to prove things directly using the definition, but it sure is a lot more convinient.

And what's "mathematical"? I'd say to use mathematical theorems in your approach would be considered "mathematical". To just avoid using them is sometimes considered purely stupid.

Answer (score 2):

I believe all the basic limits calculations are derived from the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition one way or another. And once you've proved that someting works, I'd say it's very "mathematical" to use it and not at all inconsistent.